# SWIG, perl, DynaLoader can't find boot_$Module on OS X

Tags: macos, perl, swig

I am trying to build and install a SWIG-generated perl API on OS X 10.10.2. (It's for the FreeLing 3.1 language analysis toolkit.) I have generated and compiled the SWIG files, producing `freeling.so`.

But when I try to `use freeling` in a perl script, I get the error:

```
Can't find 'boot_freeling' symbol in /usr/local/lib/libfreeling.dylib at freeling.pm line 11.
```

But `boot_freeling` should be defined in the SWIG-generated `freeling.so`, not in `libfreeling.dylib` (the FreeLing package lib). (nm -U confirms this: `_boot_freeling` is defined in freeling.so; I'm assuming the leading underscore is just part of the object file format.)

I have made sure that freeling.so comes before libfreeling.dylib in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I've also tried unshifting the path to freeling.so onto @DynaLoader::dl_library_path.

I suspect this is not a path problem, but something about building for OS X. In the past, I have built this on Ubuntu and it works fine. I have tweaked the gcc options (-bundle instead of -shared).

---

Additional info:

```
perl -V:dlext => dlext='bundle';
```

Building [SOso-0.01.patch.txt](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=921357) produces:

```
blib
├── blib/arch
│   └── blib/arch/auto
│       └── blib/arch/auto/SOso
│           └── blib/arch/auto/SOso/SOso.bundle
├── blib/bin
├── blib/lib
│   ├── blib/lib/SOso.pm
│   └── blib/lib/auto
│       └── blib/lib/auto/SOso
├── blib/man1
├── blib/man3
└── blib/script
```

Makefile target:

```
freeling.bundle: freeling_perlAPI.cxx
    g++ -v -bundle -o freeling.bundle freeling_perlAPI.cxx -lfreeling -lperl -lboost_system -I $(FREELINGDIR)/include -I $(BOOSTDIR)/include -I $(ICU4CDIR)/include -L $(FREELINGDIR)/libfreeling -I $(PERLDIR)/CORE -L $(LIBDIR) -L $(BOOSTDIR)/lib -L $(PERLDIR)/CORE -fPIC
```

Comment: What do you get for `perl -V:dlext` ? When you compile this module [SOso-0.01.patch.txt](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=921357) what files are created in blib?

Comment: @optional have provided the info requested - thanks!

Comment: Well :) if your os/perl is configured to look for a freeling.bundle, I don't think its going to try to look at freeling.so .... so I'd try to do something about that ... sure SWIG might compensate for this naming issue but I doubt it

Comment: It may that these path issues are a total red herring. If I rename freeling.so => freeling.bundle (or for that matter, tweak makefile to output freeling.bundle), then when i run my test program it segfaults (11). Does this suggest that my gcc command is screwed up?

Comment: How does it compare to the SOso Makefile?

Comment: @optional The segfault is really another question. If you want to post your suggestions as an answer, I'd be happy to award the bounty. You did resolve the path issue for me - thanks!

Comment: i'm not sure it really fits the format of stackoverflow ... so you can keep the bounty :)

Comment: I lose the bounty either way. Your insights were definitely helpful and could be preserved as a SO answer. It's up to you. Either way, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, promoting to answer :)

What do you get for `perl -V:dlext` ?
When you compile this module [SOso-0.01.patch.txt](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=921357) what files are created in blib?

Well :) if your os/perl is configured to look for a freeling.bundle, I don't think its going to try to look at freeling.so .... so I'd try to do something about that ... rename the file to use the dlext